can't figure out how to click an item in this pop up menu
i'm using keyboard maestro to click the "Edit action..." button in the actions window in REAPER.app. it pops up a menu with two items. Even though i've used a script that returns the following UI path to the menu:
menu item "Sublime Text.app" of menu "Actions" of window "Actions" of application process "REAPER" of application "System Events"
but after the next command:
click menu item "Sublime Text.app" of menu "Actions" of window "Actions" of application process "REAPER"
i get an error:
error "System Events got an error: Can’t get menu \"Actions\" of window \"Actions\" of application process \"REAPER\"." number -1728 from menu "Actions" of window "Actions" of application process "REAPER"
why won't this work? how can i fix it? i've written other applescripts to do other stuff like this in REAPER via keyboard maestro (or can also run directly from script editor). but this particular pop up menu button thing has me stumped!
